create chart for simulation data visualisation
I need advice regarding my simulation. My simulation is about 100 nodes, every node have filesystem that is populated with file storing process from other nodes. Now I want to collect data from filesystem of every node and using one chart to compare ocupied space of each nod durring time (simulation progress) ... I am using 5.6.2 omnet (this is project requirement) any advice is welcome.
I collected data from simulation using scallar data but didn t manage to make chart

OMNeT++ User Guide describes how to analyse and plot the results.
